# how to different colors to bars in sparkline chart

Tags: jquery, sparklines

I have drawn SparkLine bar chart with some data which is given below.

I achieved it, but now I want to draw red color for all '10' elements and green color for all '20' elements.

```js
$(function() {
  var myvalues = [10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20];
  $('#dynamcbar').sparkline(myvalues, {
    type: 'bar',
    barColor: 'green'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sparklines/2.1.2/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>

<body>
  <p> Bar chart with dynamic data:
    <span id="dynamcbar">Loading..</span>
  </p>
</body>
```

For '10' values the bar is not coming, it is giving a line but I want a red color bar. And for 20 a green color bar.

Comment: Please check http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-docs

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a range-map like this way

```
  var range_map = $.range_map({
    '10:': 'red',
    '20': 'green'
  })
```

Check this demo http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/pRmvZb

Comment: but i want red bars not lines

Comment: withsome height

Comment: for my convinent i put 10 for absent and 20 for present

Comment: Then just add `chartRangeMin: 0`, see updated demo in the link I placed in my answer

Comment: No big deal, glad I helped. Just remember to accept and upvote ;-)

Comment: i want to show when mouse over on 20 present and on 10 absent how can i do this

Comment: i want to show when mouse over on 20 it should display  "present" and on 10  it sholu display " absent"  how can i do this ???